# DDD Component for XML generator class

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am working on a application being build on DDD principles ,following is the project structure.

```
App (Background task) 
 --> DomainEventHandlers
   -->SomeDomnainEventHandler.cs

Domain (Class library)
 --> Models
    --> SomeAggregate.cs
    --> SomeEntity.cs
    --> SomeValueObject.cs
 Event
   --> SomeDomainEvent.cs
```

When SomeDomnainEvent is triggered, `SomeDomnainEventHandler.cs` gets called via mediator. In my `SomeDomnainEventHandler.cs` I am trying to map my `SomeEntity.cs` to an XML mapper class to generate XML messages.

My question here is, My XML mapper class and XML message generator correlate to which DDD component and where do I place them in my project structure ?

Comment: For each event are you making a XML file?

Comment: Yes my SomeDomnainEventHandler.cs maps SomeEntity.cs to generate's XML message eachtime

Comment: And are you making them manually?

Comment: I have a XmlGenerator class that uses XmlSerializer to generate XML

Comment: The XML related classes should stay in the infrastructure layer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. From DDD point of view, Can a infrastructure layer interact with the external world ?  As my XML message generator will  generate XML messages and save it at some path on the server ?  Should it be an ApplicationService ? As ApplicationService's can interact with external world!

Comment: the Infrastructure's **main** responsibility is talking to the outside world (i.e. IO operations like disk and sockets)

Comment: and Infrastructure components can be called from the Application layer

Comment: Thanks Constantin Galbenu !

Answer (score 0):

As @Constantin Galbenu stated in a comment your XML generator should be in the Infrastructure layer as 'generating XML' is non-application specific logic.

The next question is are you "mapping" your Entities directly to XML and how complex those Entities are.

If a given Entity is just a set of fields you can have a generic one-to-one relation - i.e. each Entity could be represented as a flat XML structure then you could make it work with a single entry point for all such Entities. I'd refer to what you are doing as s Transformation.

If your Entities are complex and contain specific ValueObjects then you should have a way to extract that data to a specific XML structure.

I'd actually prefer not to talk about "mapping" because of the complexity that could be involved when you have Entities containing many ValueObjects and referencing other Entities. Plus VO's are there to avoid mapping between Objects in other scenarios of a Domain.

A simple illustrative example that I could see in my head:

```
Product has the following properties:
   Name                 (String) 
   Description          (String)
   Price                (Money Value Object)
     Amount             (Decimal or integer internally)
     Currency           ()
```

This could be represented with XML:

```
<Product>
   <Name>Nm</Name>
   <Description>Desc<Description>
   <Price>
       <Amount>12.09</Amount>
       <Currency>EUR</Currency>
   </Price>
</Product>
```

or you could use XML attributes for Value Objects' representations:

```
<Product>
   <Name>Nm</Name>
   <Description>Desc<Description>
   <Price amount="12.09" currency="EUR"></Price>
</Product>
```

If you want more complex transformations from your Objects to XML you will need to have a Transformer for each Object type that you're transforming.
I'd presonally stick to XML elements since:

- attributes cannot contain multiple values (elements can)
- attributes cannot contain tree structures (elements can)
- attributes are not easily expandable (for future changes)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I was more interested in knowing,My XML mapper class and XML message generator correlate to which DDD component and where do I place them in my project structure ?

Comment: @MaheshTalreja as I said: 
"As Constantin Galbenu stated in a comment your XML generator should be in the Infrastructure layer as 'generating XML' is non-application specific logic. "